# Neural network y=f(x) regression

Tags: neural-network, regression

Encouraged by some success in MNIST classification I wanted to solve a "real" problem with some neural networks.
The task seems quite easy:

We have:

- some x-value (e.g. 1:1:100)
- some y-values (e.g. x^2)

I want to train a network with 1 input (for 1 x-value) and one output (for 1 y-value). One hidden layer.

Here is my basic procedure:

1. Slicing my x-values into different batches (e.g. 10 elements per batch)
2. In each batch calculating the outputs of the net, then applying backpropagation, calculating weight and bias updates
3. After each batch averaging the calculated weight and bias updates and actually update the weights and biases
4. Repeating step 1. - 3. multiple times

This procedure worked fine for MNIST, but for the regression it totally fails. 
I am wondering if I do something fundamentally wrong. 
I tried different batchsizes, up to averaging over ALL x values.

Basically the network does not train well. After manually tweaking the weights and biases (with 2 hidden neurons) I could approximate my y=f(x) quite well, but when the network shall learn the parameters, it fails.

When I have just one element for x and one for y and I train the network, it trains well for this one specific pair.

Maybe somebody has a hint for me. Am I misunderstanding regression with neural networks?

So far I assume, the code itself is okay, as it worked for MNIST and it works for the "one x/y pair example". I rather think my overall approach (see above) may be not suitable for regression.

Thanks,

Jim

ps: I will post some code tomorrow...

Here comes the code (MATLAB). As I said, its one hidden layer, with two hidden neurons:

```
% init hyper-parameters
hidden_neurons=2;
input_neurons=1;
output_neurons=1;
learning_rate=0.5;
batchsize=50;

% load data
training_data=d(1:100)/100;
training_labels=v_start(1:100)/255;

% init weights
init_randomly=1;
if init_randomly
    % initialize weights and bias with random numbers between -0.5 and +0.5
    w1=rand(hidden_neurons,input_neurons)-0.5;    
    b1=rand(hidden_neurons,1)-0.5;
    w2=rand(output_neurons,hidden_neurons)-0.5;
    b2=rand(output_neurons,1)-0.5;

else
    % initialize with manually determined values
    w1=[10;-10];
    b1=[-3;-0.5];
    w2=[0.2 0.2];
    b2=0;

end

for epochs =1:2000 % looping over some epochs

    for i = 1:batchsize:length(training_data) % slice training data into batches

        batch_data=training_data(i:min(i+batchsize,length(training_data))); % generating training batch
        batch_labels=training_labels(i:min(i+batchsize,length(training_data))); % generating training label batch

        % initialize weight updates for next batch
        w2_update=0;
        b2_update =0;
        w1_update =0;
        b1_update =0;        

        for k = 1: length(batch_data) % looping over one single batch

            % extract trainig sample

            x=batch_data(k); % extracting one single training sample
            y=batch_labels(k); % extracting expected output of training sample

            % forward pass

            z1 = w1*x+b1; % sum of first layer
            a1 = sigmoid(z1); % activation of first layer (sigmoid)

            z2 = w2*a1+b2; % sum of second layer
            a2=z2; %activation of second layer (linear)

            % backward pass

            delta_2=(a2-y); %calculating delta of second layer assuming quadratic cost; derivative of linear unit is equal to 1 for all x.
            delta_1=(w2'*delta_2).* (a1.*(1-a1)); % calculating delta of first layer

            % calculating the weight and bias updates averaging over one
            % batch

            w2_update = w2_update +(delta_2*a1') * (1/length(batch_data));
            b2_update = b2_update + delta_2 * (1/length(batch_data));
            w1_update = w1_update + (delta_1*x') * (1/length(batch_data));
            b1_update = b1_update + delta_1 * (1/length(batch_data));

        end

        % actually updating the weights. Updated weights will be used in
        % next batch

        w2 = w2 - learning_rate * w2_update;
        b2 = b2 - learning_rate * b2_update;        
        w1 = w1 - learning_rate * w1_update;
        b1 = b1 - learning_rate * b1_update;        

    end       
end
```

Here is the outcome with random initialization, showing the expected output, the output before training, and the output after training:
[training with random init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUKRG.png)

One can argue that the blue line is already closer than the black one, in that sense the network has optimized the results already. But I am not satisfied.
Here is the result with my manually tweaked values:
[training with pre-init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x13qK.png)

The black line is not bad for just two hidden neurons, but my expectation was rather, that such a black line would be the outcome of training starting with random init.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing to say really without code. When asking this kind of questions, it is better to wait for the code instead of making an incomplete question.

Comment: Yes, it is very difficult without code, but one problem that may be the reason would be that you're initiating your neural network weights all at the same value such as 0s or something.  This causes symmetry in your neural network, and cause the mapping in your neural network to be linear.

Comment: Agree, next time I will post the code directly... It's available now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some research I found some interesting points:

- The function I tried to learn seems particularly hard to learn (not sure why)
- With the same setup I tried to learn some 3rd degree polynomials which was successful (cost <1e-6)
- Randomizing training samples seems to improve learning (for the polynomial and my initial function). I know this is well known in literature but I always skipped that part in implementation. So I learned for myself how important it is.
- For learning "curvy/wiggly" functions, I found sigmoid works better than ReLu. (output layer is still "linear" as suggested for regression)
- a learning rate of 0.1 worked fine for the curve fitting I finally wanted to perform
- A larger batchsize would smoothen the cost vs. epochs plot (surprise...)
- Initializing weigths between -5 and +5 worked better than -0.5 and 0.5 for my application

In the end I got quite convincing results for what I intendet to learn with the network :)

Comment: Consider accepting posts as an answer to your question; [Stackoverflow explicitly encourages to accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)! Good job in figuring out your results, and nice representation of your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a much smaller learning rate? Generally, learning rates of 0.001 are a good starting point, 0.5 is in most cases way too large.

Also note that your predefined weights are in an extremely flat region of the sigmoid function (sigmoid(10) = 1, sigmoid(-10) = 0), with the derivative at both positions close to 0. That means that backpropagating from such a position (or getting *to* such a position) is extremely difficult; For exactly that reason, some people prefer to use [ReLUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) instead of sigmoid, since it has only a "dead" region for negative activations.

Also, am I correct in seeing that you only have 100 training samples? You could maybe try a smaller batch size, or increase the number of samples you take. Also don't forget to shuffle your samples after each epoch. Reasons are given plenty, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/shuffling-data-in-the-mini-batch-training-of-neural-network/311318#311318).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found that making learning rate smaller makes the whole thing worse. The sigmoid saturation seems a valid point, I will try ReLu. I just finished another training session (still with sigmoid) with significantly more epochs starting with random initialization and the results seem more promising (it almost looks like my manually determined weights). Anyway, I will switch to ReLu and post the results

Comment: I mean, ReLU is by no means a guaranteed result. If more epoch get you to convergence, too, then it was probably just an issue of terminating the training too early.